# switchMap invokes inner function multiple times

Tags: rxjs

When I apply a switchMap to an observable and return that result, I expect the subscription to that result to not cause the switch map to rerun.

Take the following code:

```
let myObservable = Observable.of('empty')
    .switchMap(id => {
        doWork();
        return Observable.of('test');
    }
);

myObservable.subscribe(x => console.log('subscription 1'));
myObservable.subscribe(x => console.log('subscription 2'));

function doWork() {
    console.log('working!');
}
```

It produces:

```
working!
subscription 1
working!
subscription 2
```

What Im looking for is the doWork method to only be called once and an output like this:

```
working!
subscription 1
subscription 2
```

**Additional Resources related to answer:**

[Cold vs Hot Observables](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple `.subscribe()` calls to the same Observable each (default) get their own instance of the subscription, thus letting it re-run. If you want your stream to be multicasting its results to multiple subscriptions you can use [`.share()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share).

Ofcourse; given the async nature of Rx even while using a multicast operator it is possible that your second subscription is too late for the initial emitted value. You can plumb everything together and when you are ready `.connect()` the upstream observable (making it hot) using [`.publish()`](https://github.com/btroncone/learn-rxjs/blob/master/operators/multicasting/publish.md)

Note: Do not `share()` all the things everywhere; it comes at a performance cost because internally it will create a reference counter and emit all values from the upstream to all observers instead of simply propagating the value from upstream downstream.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I was researching cold vs hot observables, and I believe in this case I do want a hot observable.  Is share the same as performing a publish() and then a connect()?

Comment: share() will refcount and connect() when first stream subscribes. publish() lets you subscribe all the things before connect()'ing and start receiving upstream emissions

Comment: Is this type of RxJs programming an antipattern?  Should I look for alternative ways to do this?

Comment: Really depends on your usecase. Making all your streams multicast is a smell for a design issue but It is not directly a bad thing.